# 2011 Infiniti G25x: water is leaking down from the passenger glove compartment onto the floor

Tags: ac, water-leak, infiniti, sunroof

It was raining, and I was driving. I parked my car, and discover the water is leaking down from the passenger glove compartment onto the floor. I have recorded a video to show this problem: https://youtu.be/L7lvlU6V_Ng. The last 5 seconds show the water is clearly dropping down.

Basic on my research, it could be the following reason

1. There is a blockage in the sunroof drain pipe.
2. The AC drain is blocked.

What do you think it's the cause?

Comment: Was the air conditioning/defrost turned on?

Comment: AC was on for very cold, like 65 F.

Answer (score 2):

AC drain tube is clogged, find it in the engine compartment on the lower firewall area, passenger side. Run a wire or other suitable device to clear the drain tube.

If it starts leaking again a few days later, rotoroot the drain tube again.

Comment: Online, people suggest using an air compressor to blow air into the drain hole. If there is debris in the drainpipe, where will the debris go then after blowing in the air?

Comment: @user1187968 and using compressed air can blow the drain pipe off the other end so then the water drips down behind the carpet... be very careful with the pressure you apply.

Comment: Compressed air is a bad idea, it will blow debris back into the evaporator box, don't do it.